# Action dispatch not updating state in Redux/React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, action

I'm dispatching an action from a component, everything looks like it's linked properly but when I console.log the state in my component props it has not updated.

I have tried reformatting my code and looked at multiple examples, and it looks like it's supposed to run? When I log from the reducer it's receiving the action it's just not updating the state.

```
    const mapStateToProps = state => ({
         todos: state
    });

    onSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let payload = this.state.content
        this.props.dispatch(post_todo(payload));
        console.log(this.props.todos)
        this.setState({
            content: ""
        })
    }
```

```
export default (
  state = [],
  action
) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case POST_TODO:
      console.log("got it")
      console.log(action.payload)
      console.log(state)
      return [
        ...state,
        action.payload
      ];
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

```
export function post_todo (payload){
    return {
        type: POST_TODO,
        payload
    };
}
```

It should update the props.todos to the proper state but its showing an empty array everytime.

Comment: If you are expecting the `console.log(this.props.todos)` on the next line after `this.props.dispatch(post_todo(payload));` to immediately reflect the state change, then it doesn't work that way. Your component has to go through an update loop. You should expect to see the updated `this.props.todos` in the next render call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let payload = this.state.content
    this.props.dispatch(post_todo(payload)); <=== this line
    console.log(this.props.todos)
    this.setState({
        content: ""
    })
}
```

when you dispatch you action at the line I'm point at, it will go and exec your actions, and then you could receive the newly updated props in an event like `componentWillReceiveProps` ...

receiving new `props` to your component will cause your component to re `render`

So, console logging your props **immediately after** executing your action, will never give you the `new state` ... wait for it in `componentWillReceiveProps` or `render` methods

here's an example of how to get your new props (todos) in your case:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  const { todos } = nextProps;

  console.log('I recieved new todos', todos);
}
```

also, if your `render` method render any component that display this `todos` field that you grap from `this.props.todos` ... also will be updated automatically...

Comment: so how can i check when if the state has been rendered properly

Comment: Holy crap! thank you so much! I had it right all along!

Comment: glad it helps ... happy coding!

Comment: Hey @HendEl-Sahli can you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60591099/how-can-i-avoid-slow-get-state-from-the-redux-store) question, please?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the store from the component immediately as It'll contain the new value which hasn't made it yet to the component

```
import store  from "../../redux/configureStore"
const requiredState = store.getState()[path of the required value];
```

I'm not sure if this is an anti-pattern though.