# How can I avoid slow get state from the Redux store?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I have App contains Tabs that gets data from API bassed on token I passed to the header request,

So in the login screen, i dispatch an action to save token after user login and it's saved well

But the issue is after user login and go to home screen "save token  Action dispatched" I got error 401 unauthorized, and when I log Token in getting data function I got *empty* in the debugger although save token dispatched".

But when I open the app again after killing App and Go to Home **" because I'm login before and save token, And I use `redux-persist` to save it so it's saved before when logging first time"** its work fine!

So I don't know whats the wrong When Login at first time!

here's Home Screen Code snippet

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      token: this.props.token,
    }
   }


  // Get all playList user created
  getAllPlayLists = async () => {
    const {token} = this.state;
    console.log(token); // After first time I login I got here empty, But after i kill the app or re-open it i got the token well :)
    let AuthStr = `Bearer ${token}`;
    const headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: AuthStr,
    };

    let response = await API.get('/my_play_list', {headers: headers});
    let {
      data: {
        data: {data},
      },
    } = response;
    this.setState({playlists: data});
  };
  componentDidMount() {
      this.getAllPlayLists();
  }



const mapStateToProps = state => {
  console.log('is??', state.token.token); here's i got the token :\\
  return {
    token: state.token.token,
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Home);
```

**Redux stuff**

*reducers*

```
import {SAVE_TOKEN} from '../actions/types';

let initial_state = {
  token: '',
};
const saveTokenReducer = (state = initial_state, action) => {
  const {payload, type} = action;
  switch (type) {
    case SAVE_TOKEN:
      state = {
        ...state,
        token: payload,
      };
      break;
  }
  return state;
};

export default saveTokenReducer;
```

--

```
import {IS_LOGIN} from '../actions/types';

let initialState = {
  isLogin: false,
};

const userReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case IS_LOGIN:
      state = {
        ...state,
        isLogin: true,
      };
      break;
    default:
      return state;
  }
  return state;
};

export default userReducer;
```

*actions*

```
import {SAVE_TOKEN} from './types';

export const saveToken = token => {
  return {
    type: SAVE_TOKEN,
    payload: token,
  };
};
```

-

```
import {IS_LOGIN} from './types';

export const isLoginFunc = isLogin => {
  return {
    type: IS_LOGIN,
    payload: isLogin,
  };
};
```

*store*

```
const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage: AsyncStorage,
};

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  user: userReducer,
  count: countPlayReducer,
  favorite: isFavoriteReducer,
  token: saveTokenReducer,
});

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);
```

### Edit

I figure out the problem, Now in the Login function after getting the response from the API I dispatch two actions Respectively

```
facebookAuth = async()=>{
....
 this.props.dispatch(isLoginFunc(true));  // first

 this.props.dispatch(saveToken(token)); // second
....
}
```

But when I dispatch `saveToken(token)` **firstly** I can see the token in the debugger without problems!

So how can i handle it and dispatch two actions at the same time?

Comment: How do you save ```token```?

Comment: @SDushan after login and got the response from API I call `this.props.dispatch(saveToken(token));`

Comment: did you save it in ```AsyncStorage``` or only in ```state```

Comment: @SDushan I use `redux-persist` and it's handling AsyncStorage in persistConfig, So I think both s

Comment: @SDushan I figure out the issue can you check the EDIT section?

Answer (score 0):

When response token get then redirect to page. Maybe should add callback function for action. For example:

This following code is for add record

```
addVideoGetAction(values, this.props.data, this.callBackFunction)
```

This callBackFunction is close the modal

```
callBackFunction = (value: any) => {
    this.setCloseModal();
};
```

You will use callback function in login action. This function will redirect to the page

This function call in saga. this following code

```
function* setAddOrUpdate(params: any) {
        params.callback(redirectPageParams);
}
```

Comment: Hmm I don't understand you! Which modal? Redirect page?

Comment: This code is from my application. You change code for this. This code is click add button then insert record then will get response for server then close modal. You use click login form then will get response data then redirect page. Because you redirect without login token

Answer (score 0):

In redux we should NEVER alter the `state` object in reducer ... we return a brand new object

```
const saveTokenReducer = (state = initial_state, action) => {
  const {payload, type} = action;
  switch (type) {
    case SAVE_TOKEN:
      state = {
        ...state,
        token: payload,
      };
      break;
  }
  return state;
};
```

**Instead**

```
const saveTokenReducer = (state = initial_state, action) => {
  const { payload, type } = action;
  switch (type) {
    case SAVE_TOKEN:
      return { ...state, token: payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

**Regarding dispatching two actions at the same time**

```
const userReducer = (state = initial_state, { action, type }) => {
  switch (type) {
    case UPDATE_LOGIN:
      return { ...state, token: payload, isLogin: !!payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

-

```
facebookAuth = async () => {
  this.props.dispatch(updateLogin(token));
};
```

-

```
import { UPDATE_LOGIN } from './types';

export const updateLogin = token => {
  return {
    type: UPDATE_LOGIN,
    payload: token,
  };
};
```

Comment: Hey, @HendEl-Sahli, I figure out the issue can you check the EDIT section?

Comment: @OliverD ... you want to dispatch two actions at the same time .... why not you make them ONE_ACTION ? ...

Comment: If I understand you well, It's not related, And I used one of them in other screens

Comment: @OliverD then please include `isLoginFunc ` action in your question ... to clear the pic a bit

Comment: Well, check it out again, please:)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209429/discussion-between-oliver-d-and-hend-el-sahli).

Comment: I send you a message in chat can you check it, please?

Comment: @OliverD I replied ... check it out